# Stop Emoji Rendering with ggplot on Mac

Tags: r, macos, ggplot2, unicode, emoji

I am trying to use the unicode cross symbol in ggplot, and it works fine if I am only trying to put the unicode for the cross in as the label. However, if I add any characters after the unicode, the cross becomes the emoji for the cross, which is not what I want. I am trying to make a key that says *cross* = something, but the cross always becomes an emoji.

This first line of code yields the first image with the text symbol of a cross

```
annotate("label", x = 3, y = 1, label = "\U271D")
```

[Picture of unicode cross in ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Gwg.png)

While any of these lines yields the other images with the emoji of a cross

```
annotate("label", x = 3, y = 1, label = "\U271D ")
annotate("label", x = 3, y = 1, label = "\U271D=More Text")
```

[Picture of emoji cross in ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm180.png)
[Picture of emoji cross in ggplot with more text beside it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmZtO.png)

I expected to be able to add more text with out it printing as an emoji. How can I stop it rendering as an emoji?

Edit: This problem is specifically occurring on MacOS, I am running Ventura 13.5.1

Comment: On Windows 11, R 3.4.1, ggplot2 version 3.4.3 I cannot reproduce this error, both crosses are the same unicode character.

Comment: Thank you for trying to reproduce the error. I should have been more specific about my operating system. I have edited the post to specify this is occurring on MacOS

Comment: Had a look at your issue and can reproduce it on my Mac. My guess is that this is related to the graphics device, i.e. this happens only when using `ragg` or `AGG`. whereas switching the graphics device to `Cairo` "fixes" the issue.